# Simplifying a Java IF or CASE statement

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I have an XML file that has four fields

```
<field1>
<field2>
<field3>
<field4>
```

The values of these fields can be either TRUE or FALSE. I want to decide whether the output will be A, B, C or D. To do this i have to look at these four fields and every combination means that the output is either A, B, C or D. The possible combinations and outputs are as described below:

```
1T, 2F, 3F, 4F; A
1T, 2T, 3F, 4F; B
1T, 2T, 3T, 4F; C
1T, 2T, 3T, 4T; C
1T, 2F, 3T, 4F; A
1T, 2F, 3T, 4T; A
1T, 2F, 3F, 4T; A
1T, 2T, 3F, 4T; B
```

The number represents the field number and the character after the number represents whether the value is TRUE or false, for example, the first combination `(-1T, 2F, 3F, 4F; A)` is saying if field1 is TRUE, field2 is false, field3 is false then the output is A.
The output is D if there is no match.

Obviously i can do something like

```
if(field1, !field2, !field3, !field4)
 return 'A'
else if(field1, field2, !field3, !field4)
 return 'B'
else if(field1, field2, field3, !field4)
 return 'C'
...
....
....
and so on
```

The caveat is that some of these fields can be null (i.e the tag might not exist). Short of having 100s of IF statements, is there an easier way to code these combinations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: Group them, for example field 1 will always have to be true (from what I can gather) so just wrap the rest of your if's in check for that. Then you can do the other 3 inside in a similar fashion

Comment: Are you missing some possible outputs, or will value 1 always be true?

Comment: How should a null be handled - as `false` or as a 3rd state that would not participate in matching any combination listed?

Comment: @RyanS that is a decision tree, isn't it?

Comment: @user270349 yes, I guess I could have said that XD

Comment: The field has to exist for the output to be provided. So if the field is missing it doesn't mean the value is false. It just means that combination is not valid.

Comment: Value 1 is always true

Comment: It is all in the field2 and field3 whether it is either of those numbers.

Comment: You said that `D` is a possible output, but it isn't associated with any of the combinations you listed. And why are you even mentioning `field1` if it's always `true`? That doesn't carry any information. It has no effect on the output. Likewise the fourth field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a tool called a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) which is used specifically for simplifying that kind of logic.

It's been half a decade since I've had to touch one, but there's tons of information on the subject if you search for it.

---

And that's not the only approach if you want to get creative.

You can aggregate your fields into a single value and use a map, ([Actual map syntax here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html))

```
myMap["TFTF"] = 'A'
```

and I'm sure that you can find other creative ways like that if you think about the problem more

Answer (score 2):

You can encode the values somehow to a number so each combination gives a number that is not given for any other combination.

That encoding may be just binary.

```
1000=8  A
1100=12 B
1110=14 C
1111=16 C
1010=10 A
1011=11 A
1001=9  A
1101=13 B
```

Then you need a data structure like a map to associate each number with the output.

**EDIT**: I said a number but indeed any encoding may work as well as maps allow almost anything as key. Other encodings: `"TFFF", "1000", "1T 2F 3F 4F", Arrays.asList(true, false, false, false)` ...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how "dense" the table is, you may just want to treat the fields as binary digits, construct the corresponding number and then do an array lookup:

```
  234
0 000: A
1 001: A
2 010: A
3 011: A
4 100: B
5 101: B
6 110: C
7 111: C

int x = (field2 ? 4 : 0) + (field3 ? 2 : 0) + (field4 ? 1 : 0)
return "AAAABBCC".charAt(x);
```

For the example, this would just work btw (field4 and 1 are not relevant for the output):

```
return field2 ? (field3 ? 'C' : 'B') : 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll go for this kind of thing, as follows (pseudo code):

```
int c=0;
array r[4]= [field1, field2, field3, field4];

for(int i=0; i<4; i++) { 

    if (!r[i]) break;

    c++;
}

return 'A'+c;
```

Depending on how you want to handle null, you silly add a test if (r[i] is null) {}

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify things with a lookup table:

```
table[1][0][0][0] = 'A'
table[1][1][0][0] = 'B'
table[1][1][1][0] = 'C'
table[1][1][1][1] = 'C'
table[1][0][1][0] = 'A'
table[1][0][1][1] = 'A'
table[1][0][0][1] = 'A'
table[1][1][0][1] = 'B'
```

Make a function to turn the field into a 1 or a 0 then plug those in to the table and get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of the pattern, if we are just using that data set we can test it simply by doing:

```
if (field3 && field2) 
    return 'C';
else if (!field3 && field2) 
    return 'B';
else 
    return 'A';
```

Comment: `if (field3 && field2)` this is already not true because for example:
`FTTT` will be `D`

Comment: I said in my answer for the data set that we see in the question. I don't know if there will ever be a D as I only saw those 8 fields.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so first you need to safely handle the null values. You can write two methods for this purpose:

```
boolean safeTrue(Boolean b){
    return b != null && b.booleanValue();
}

boolean safeFalse(Boolean b){
    return b != null && !(b.booleanValue());
}
```

After that, you can indeed reduce your boolean expressions by using Karnaugh diagrams, as suggested by some other fellows here. The result would be:

```
if(safeTrue(field1) && safeFalse(field2)){
    return 'A';
}
if(safeTrue(field1) && safeTrue(field2) && safeFalse(field3)){
    return 'B';
}
if(safeTrue(field1) && safeTrue(field2) && safeTrue(field3)){
    return 'C';
}
//finally, return some value for the case when no combiantion has been matched.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read it this way and represent it binary it's:

```
1T, 2F, 3F, 4F; A 1000 (8)
1T, 2F, 3F, 4T; A 1001 (9)
1T, 2F, 3T, 4F; A 1010 (10)
1T, 2F, 3T, 4T; A 1011 (11)
1T, 2T, 3F, 4F; B 1100 (12)
1T, 2T, 3F, 4T; B 1101 (13)
1T, 2T, 3T, 4F; C 1110 (14)
1T, 2T, 3T, 4T; C 1111 (15)
```

So:

```
if binaryRepr>=8 && binaryRepr<=11 then A
if binaryRepr>=12 && bicnaryRepr<=13 then B
if binaryRepr>=14 then C
else D
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the list of inputs and outputs, you only need `field2`and `field3`. Then, I would suggest the following:

```
if (!field2)
   return 'A';
else if (field3)
   return 'C';
else 
   return 'B';
```

With this solution you should deal with possible `null` values before the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the cases you listed, the first and fourth fields are irrelevant, and all you need is this:

```
char foo(boolean field2, boolean field3)
{
    return field2 ? (field3 ? 'C' : 'B') : 'A';
}
```